# Java get network connection list

Tags: java, windows, networking

I am trying to get the list of network connections in Windows platform using Java. I am able to get the network adapters with the following code

```
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaceList = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        ArrayList<NetworkInterface> interfaces = new ArrayList<>(Collections.list(interfaceList));     

        for (NetworkInterface aInterface : interfaces) {
            if (aInterface.isLoopback() ||
                aInterface.isVirtual())
                continue;
            System.out.println(aInterface.getName() + ": " + aInterface.isUp());
        }
```

But this is not what I am looking for. This gives me a very long list of network interfaces. In windows, when you go to Network Connections window, you will probably get one Wireless connection, one network connections and a Bluetooth if you have the adapter. This is the list I want to retrieve in Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `! aInterface.isUp()` to the condition.
This will reduce the list to active interfaces only.